# PHP preg_match_all regex expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

```
<td align="center" valign="middle" style="color:White;background-color:Red;font-weight:bold;">(.*?)</td>
```

I can not get any data. Can you help for regex?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3294262

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it RegExp template you show us?

This should be like this in php:

```
$exp = '<td align="center" valign="middle" style="color:White;background-color:Red;font-weight:bold;">(.*?)</td>';
$subject_string = '';
preg_match_all("|{$exp}|U",
    subject_string,
    $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

So, $out[0] contains array of strings that matched full pattern, and $out[1] contains array of strings enclosed by TD tag.

Don't forget to wrap your expression like shown in example - "|{$exp}|U"

For more info watch this - http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: With templates you have given "subject_string" as an example instead of '<td align = "center" valign = "middle" style = "color: White; background-color: red; font-weight: bold;"> 67 </ td> 'I'm taking the summer when 67 value. But how do I get all this value in the page?